# R:: How to check for two different values for a variable in IF condition

Tags: r

I have to check the for a  condition like this:

```
 IF COUNTRY_QUOTATION in {CAD, JPY} &
    RATING_MOODY <= -1 &
    COUPON_TYPE <= 3 &
    CONVEXITY > 0.39 & 
      THEN  CLUSTER_ID = 1
```

How to check for the two values in R for the variable COUNTRY_QUOTATION?

```
IF (COUNTRY_QUOTATION in {CAD, JPY} &
        RATING_MOODY <= -1 &
        COUPON_TYPE <= 3 &
        CONVEXITY > 0.39 ){

        CLUSTER_ID <- 1

}
```

if is one value we can just put "==" for the presence of a value. However I want to check for two different values. The "IF" condition has to pass if either of the values are present.

Please help.

Comment: Please show a reproducible example.  I guess you need `%in%`  Also, I `R`, you keep the elements inside `c(...)`

Comment: Use `%in% c("CAD", "JPY")`, or if CAD and JPY are variables, `%in% c(CAD, JPY)`

Comment: @DavidRobinson - Thanks for the response. It has worked.

Comment: @akrun - Thank you. It has worked. Thanks for pointing out the mistake that i have missed c(...). Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @akrun  & @David pointed out in the comments space, I have  included %in%  to validate more than two values in a variable.

```
%in% c("CAD", "JPY")
```

Thanks for the quick response.